# Find in JSON response and edit it to post it again

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a complicated JSON

I want to edit multiple values and post it again
I want to replace every "SKU" with a diffrent value

```
data = {
"products": [
   {
        "name": {
            "ar": "PRODUCT_NAME",
            "en": "PRODUCT_NAME"
        },
        "description": {
            "ar": "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION",
            "en": "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION"
        },
        "preparation_time_in_minutes": 4,
        "image_path": "https://path/to/image.png",
        "index": 0,
        "pricing_type": 1,
        "selling_type": 1,
        "sku": "",
        "created_at": "2018-05-08 12:53:55",
        "updated_at": "2018-08-30 21:03:20",
        "taxable": "true",
        "is_combo": "false",
        "calories": "null",
        "is_active": "true",
        "hid": "_a7g34337",
        "barcode": "PRODUCT_BARCODE",
        "category": {
            "hid": "_697d1127"
        },
        "tags": [
           {
                "hid": "_16718997",
                "relationship_data": {
                    "index": 0
                }
            }
        ],
        "modifiers": [
           {
                "hid": "_567a437a",
                "relationship_data": {
                    "index": 0,
                    "is_required": "false",
                    "minimum_options": 0,
                    "maximum_options": 100,
                    "excluded_options": [
                        "_567a437a"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "timed_events": [
           {
                "hid": "_567a437a"
            }
        ],
        "sizes": [
           {
                "name": {
                    "en": "SIZE_NAME",
                    "ar": "SIZE_NAME"
                },
                "price": 20,
                "index": 0,
                "created_at": "2018-09-04 14:46:24",
                "updated_at": "2018-09-04 14:46:24",
                "barcode": "SIZE_BARCODE",
                "calories": 123,
                "sku": "",
                "cost": 0,
                "has_fixed_cost": "false",
                "hid": "_273ad637",
                "costingType": "ingredients",
                "ingredients": [
                   {
                        "hid": "_d741agg7",
                        "relationship_data": {
                            "is_optional": "false",
                            "quantity": 40,
                            "inactive_in_order_types": [
                                1,
                                2
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "special_branch_prices": [
                   {
                        "branch_hid": "_d741agg7",
                        "price": 23
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
] }
```

I want to find first "SKU" and replace its value

then look again to find any other "SKU" and replace the value

I tried to find put the place of the "SKU" is changing in every request

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first sku, try this:

```
data["products"][0]["sku"] = "What you want"
```

and for the second one, try this:

```
data["products"][0]["sizes"][0]["sku"] = "What you want x2"
```

Can you see what's happening here? We first need to tell the system that we want to read data. Then inside of data, we want to read products, which has a list inside of it, which we want to want to get the first element of, which is 0. Inside of this list, we want find "sku", as it's there.

Now, inside of the same list, there's another element called "sizes", that has a list, where one of the elements is "sku". So we simply access that too, and change it.

Comment: I could be wrong about this but I think OP is looking for an automated solution for an arbitrary number of `"sku"` that can show up on different levels of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you wish to have it automated and the value is always the same for each product you could do something like

```
def modify_value_from_json_by_key(json_input, lookup_key, new_value):
    if isinstance(json_input, dict):
        for k, v in json_input.items():
            if k == lookup_key:
                json_input[k] = new_value
            else:
                modify_value_from_json_by_key(v, lookup_key, new_value)
    elif isinstance(json_input, list):
        for item in json_input:
            modify_value_from_json_by_key(item, lookup_key, new_value)

modify_value_from_json_by_key(data, "sku", "your_new_value")
```

this will output:

```
data = {
"products": [{
        "name": {
            "ar": "PRODUCT_NAME",
            "en": "PRODUCT_NAME"
        },
        "description": {
            "ar": "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION",
            "en": "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION"
        },
        "preparation_time_in_minutes": 4,
        "image_path": "https://path/to/image.png",
        "index": 0,
        "pricing_type": 1,
        "selling_type": 1,
        "sku": "your_new_value",
        "created_at": "2018-05-08 12:53:55",
        "updated_at": "2018-08-30 21:03:20",
        "taxable": "true",
        "is_combo": "false",
        "calories": "null",
        "is_active": "true",
        "hid": "_a7g34337",
        "barcode": "PRODUCT_BARCODE",
        "category": {
            "hid": "_697d1127"
        },
        "tags": [
           {
                "hid": "_16718997",
                "relationship_data": {
                    "index": 0
                }
            }
        ],
        "modifiers": [
           {
                "hid": "_567a437a",
                "relationship_data": {
                    "index": 0,
                    "is_required": "false",
                    "minimum_options": 0,
                    "maximum_options": 100,
                    "excluded_options": [
                        "_567a437a"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "timed_events": [
           {
                "hid": "_567a437a"
            }
        ],
        "sizes": [
           {
                "name": {
                    "en": "SIZE_NAME",
                    "ar": "SIZE_NAME"
                },
                "price": 20,
                "index": 0,
                "created_at": "2018-09-04 14:46:24",
                "updated_at": "2018-09-04 14:46:24",
                "barcode": "SIZE_BARCODE",
                "calories": 123,
                "sku": "your_new_value",
                "cost": 0,
                "has_fixed_cost": "false",
                "hid": "_273ad637",
                "costingType": "ingredients",
                "ingredients": [
                   {
                        "hid": "_d741agg7",
                        "relationship_data": {
                            "is_optional": "false",
                            "quantity": 40,
                            "inactive_in_order_types": [
                                1,
                                2
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "special_branch_prices": [
                   {
                        "branch_hid": "_d741agg7",
                        "price": 23
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

If you get more products in your list and the value has to be different for each "product", you could try something like:

```
for product in data["products"]:
    title = product.get('name').get("en")
    if title == 'something_you_want_to_modify':
        sku = 'product_sku_{}'.format(title)
        modify_value_from_json_by_key(product, "sku", sku)
```

**Edited**

```
for product in data['products']:
    product['sku'] = 'your custom sku'
    if 'sizes' in product:
        product['sizes'][0]['sku'] = 'a different sku for you!' # if sizes only contains a single item in the list
        # if sizes contains more items iterate through product['sizes'] and set each desires value
```

Comment: The problem in here is that the first SKU is different from the second one even in the same response, Thank you !

Comment: I'll expand my answer. Maybe that will help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I've quickly created a recursion-based function which iterates through a python dictionary - `json.loads(data)`.

```
def replaceKey(data, key_to_replace = 'sku', string_to_insert = ''):
    for key in data.keys():
        if (type(data[key]) is list and type(data[key][0]) is dict):
            for el in data[key]:
                replaceKey(el)
        elif (type(data[key]) is dict):
            replaceKey(data[key])
        elif (key == key_to_replace):
            data[key_to_replace] = string_to_insert
```